# How to save route table after restarting on Fedora 18

Tags: fedora, routes

experts,

I need change route table on Fedora 18, using commands like this:

```
ip route add 9.0.0.0/8 via 9.111.222.1 dev em1
```

and then, "route -n", found it had taken affect.

But after restarting the machine, the route table was lost.

My question is:
How can I save route table after rebooting the OS? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This is not a programming question. Probably better chances if you ask it at a fedora or general linux forum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this is no linux forum, here is the answer:
http://www.linuxscrew.com/2008/05/09/faq-static-routes-after-restartreboot-in-fedoraredhatcentos/

You have to add it to /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1, as described in the link